# How do I rotate an image around its center in jsPDF?

Tags: jspdf

When I rotate an image by any (45, 90, 180) degrees in jsPDF using addImage, the image changes its position in unpredictable way.

I don't understand what I need to do to handle this behavior.

I facing same problem with addText.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ejg93n?file=App.tsx

Comment: Please don't post images for text content, nor links to external code. You should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to help people help you.

Comment: In my view, jsPDF is awfully buggy. For instance on SO you will find people (no jokers, apparently) who say they do not "believe"  the method forHTML exists, while it works (to some extent). The documentation of jsPDF is very poor, poorly worded and erratic.